# json validate with json schema in powershell

Tags: json, validation, powershell

Here is my code to validate json with jsonschema in powershell. and its error ed with following error message.

**Cannot find an overload for "Validate" and the argument count: "2".**

```
$json =   Get-Content -Raw -Path C:\temp\locationstores.json
$SchmeaJson = Get-Content -Raw -Path C:\temp\LocationstoreSchema.json
NewtonsoftJsonAssembly =  [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\temp\Json100r3\Bin\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")
$NewtonsoftJsonSchemaAssembly =  [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\temp\JsonSchema30r3\Bin\net45\NewtonSoft.Json.Schema.dll")
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\JsonSchema30r3\Bin\net45\NewtonSoft.Json.Schema.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Json100r3\Bin\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
[Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions]::Validate([Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]::Parse($json), [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema]::Parse($SchmeaJson))
```

Please can some one let me know what is the error and any other way to validate json with json schema in powershell..

Comment: "Here is my code". Please post it.

Comment: did you post something... code missing..

Comment: are you trying to load the json file as json?

Also what line is it erroring at?

Comment: If `JsonSchema30r3`is supposed to indicate you're using version 3.0 of NewtonSoft.Json: that version is ancient (we're at 10.0.3), and if the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_SchemaExtensions_Validate.htm) are an indication, also possibly too old to have that overload. Get some code compiling in C# first, if possible.

Comment: ok so looks like [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions]::Validate requires 3 params. Source, Schema, Event. 
Try       [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions]::Validate([Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]::Parse($json), [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema]::Parse($SchmeaJson), $Null)

Comment: Its erroring out

Comment: Yes, am ttrying load json file json and json schema as json.. please let me know is it right?

Comment: Just closed the powershell window and opened again ran the script and its running fine now. Thanks for all your support..

Comment: again its stopped running, dont know why

Comment: @ArcSet yes am trying to load json file as json and its erroring @ [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions]::Validate([Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]::Parse($json1), [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema]::Parse($SchmeaJson1),$Null)

Comment: Post where its erroring and what the error is in your post

Comment: erorring in this line [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions]::Validate([Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]::Parse($json), [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema]::Parse($SchmeaJson))                                         error message :  Cannot find an overload for "Validate" and the argument count: "2".
 at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Ramu.Kalakoti\Documents\APITests\APITests\Diff\JsonSchemaToValidate2.Tests.ps1: line 21
 21: [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions]::Validate([Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]::Parse($json), [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema]::Parse($SchmeaJson))

Answer (score 0):

You could try an alternative method call:

Example C# code to adapt:

```
public void ValidateWithOutEventHandlerFailure()
{
        //...
        JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse("{'pattern':'lol'}");
        JToken stringToken = JToken.FromObject("pie");
        stringToken.Validate(schema);
```

Source: JSON.NET unit tests at 
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/aa5f28c09732db5fb3e316433547ea7cdecd8804/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/Schema/ExtensionsTests.cs

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Hi, am new to .net and trying to implement in powershell, it was working in one window and closed that window trying in new window and its stopped working am not sure why... please see if i can add something in the code to make it run...